# How to retain a state variable value even after submitting a button in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display a table of records for an Id through a GET axios request.

Now, if I want to again get the table of records, I need to again enter a text input and click on submit button.

I want to reduce this manual effort of every time entering an input.

How to retain the state variable even after submitting the button ?

```
class Report extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            requestId: null,
            api: this.props.api,
            result: undefined,
        }
    }

    updateInput = event => {
        this.setState({ 
            requestId: event.target.value
         });
    };

    handleSubmit = () => {

        const url = this.state.api;    
        axios
        .get(url + this.state.requestId)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                result: response.data
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.updateInput} placeholder="Enter Id" />
                <input 
                    className='block' 
                    type="submit" 
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit} 
                />
                {this.state.result ? 
                    <div>
                        <table className="styled-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{this.state.result.Id}</th>
                                <td>{this.state.result.Name}</td>
                                <td>{this.state.result.Address}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div> : <div> </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the input type `submit` to `button`.

```
class Report extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            requestId: null,
            api: this.props.api,
            result: undefined,
        }
    }

    updateInput = event => {
        this.setState({ 
            requestId: event.target.value
         });
    };

    handleBtnClick = () => {

        const url = this.state.api;    
        axios
        .get(url + this.state.requestId)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                result: response.data
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.updateInput} placeholder="Enter Id" />
                <input 
                    className='block' 
                    type="button" 
                    onClick={this.handleBtnClick} 
                />
                {this.state.result ? 
                    <div>
                        <table className="styled-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{this.state.result.Id}</th>
                                <td>{this.state.result.Name}</td>
                                <td>{this.state.result.Address}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div> : <div> </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```